# Periodic polling an external webservice in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'm evaluating Camel for creating an integration between two decoupled systems. I need Camel to periodically poll a web service for a list of items, do some transformations on the received items and send it to a second system using a different transport.

I've tried the following approach:

```
<route id="timer">
        <from uri="timer://myTimer?period=5000"/>
        <to uri="direct:queryWS"/>
    </route>
    <route id="ws">
        <from uri="direct:queryWS"/>
        <to uri="log:Querying WS"/>
        <process ref="itemRetriever" />
    </route>
```

where itemRetriever is a bean I've previously set up, which implements org.apache.camel.Processor and does the web service call using Axis. However, when the message gets to the second route, Camel throws an exception because the message body is null.

I'm wondering if there is a better way of periodically polling an external web service, or at least how to get past this error.

Comment: Two things a) why do you need to make this as two routes. This could be one route, <from "timer"..>.<to "log:"..<process... b) You dont seem to set a body anwhere in the route, i suspect you are trying to act on the in message body in the processor. More exception details would help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question? What version of camel are you using, what is the stacktrace, etc

Comment: Finally, it was a totally different problem. Seems Camel is wrapping the exceptions in other exceptions, so that a "Class def not found" exception caused by a missing library shows up as "message body is null". I had to set a breakpoint in org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange to see what the real problem was

Comment: If you found an answer yourself, consider posting it so it may help someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found out since, is exceptions in camel will get hidden under "Message body is null", but the problem could be quite different, and none of the stack traces you see lead you to the original problem. I had to trace the code step by step to find out that the original problem was that I was missing a dependency.

Bottom line is: above code should work correctly. And if you see the "message body is null" exception, the problem is usually something in a different layer.